# How to align and get rid of overlapping videos?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these videos I'm "posting" to a website I'm building. The first two videos align right (or so I thought) but every video after that overlaps and I can't figure out why can someone help or give advice? I've tried adding style just for a temporary fix but it does move around the screen when I inert the code.

```css
.embed-container {
 position: sticky;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
 padding-bottom: 56.27198%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.embed-container iframe {
 position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

```html
<div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GT_J4eEnmG4" "
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" width="70%" height="100%" align="center">
   </iframe>
  </div>


  <div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_5Jwb0Ophdc"" 
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  width="50%" height="150%" align="center">
   </iframe>
  </div>
  
  <div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PVY4wjF_lvo"" 
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  width="60%" height="70%" align="center" >
   </iframe>
  </div>
  
  <div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hXg78e7L3I8" " 
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  width="70%" height="100%" align="center">
   </iframe>
  </div>
  
  <div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vRE9XwMmg_o" "
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  width="50%" height="150%" align="center">
   </iframe>
  </div>
  
  <div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EgdO6DxBAvI" " 
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  width="50%" height="150%" align="center">
   </iframe>
  </div>
  
  <div class='embed-container'>
   <iframe src="<iframe width="916" height="515" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6zSRRfevpRw" "
   allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"  width="50%" height="150%" align="center">
   </iframe>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not have any margins between your videos.Add `margin-bottom` in your embed-container class and it should work. You should look into grid systems or flexbox to do layouts I think that will be a more sustained solution.
For now just change your embed-container class with this.You can also tweak the margin according to your need.

```
.embed-container {
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.27198%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
 }
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you have more doubts.

Comment: Thanks, I started looking into "flexbox" I think I need to work towards learning when is best to use it and how it exactly works, but thank you again.